# Does free revving a diesel engine to 4000 rpm (1.6 crdi- hyundai) cause any damage?

Tags: engine, diesel, hyundai, pressure

It's a Hyundai CRETA/ ix25 model... clocked 1800kms on the odometer, diesel spec engine 1.6 crdi unit, manual transmission! It has redline at about 4800rpm in the tachometer. When i took it for service! the idiotic mechanic FREE REVVED the engine upto 4000rpm for 2-3 times:@ both in neutral and in running the vehicle with clutch in ... i've heard that free revving an engine damages it!

I felt really annoyed.  Does it eat up engines life?

I'm worried!...Please help

Comment: Short answer - no. It's perfectly okay. And , it's also perfectly okay to be annoyed. It's one of those things mechanics like to do (no offence to anyone). Similar to endlessly hitting refresh on a windows machine. Your car has a rev limiter and unless you've crossed that by downshifting, there's no need to be worried.

Comment: @chilljeet - You should post this as the answer ... Spot on.

Comment: @chilljeet  use your post as an answer!   :-)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, DucatiKiller & paulster haha, yes doing that now :)

Answer (score 8):

Short answer - no. It's perfectly okay. And , it's also perfectly okay to be annoyed. It's one of those things mechanics like to do (no offence to anyone). Similar to endlessly hitting refresh on a windows machine. 
Your car, as do most modern cars, has a rev-limiter and unless you've crossed that by downshifting, there's no need to be worried.

Please comment if there's anything you'd like me to elaborate on.

Comment: Very nice.. +1!

Comment: I remember "mechanic friends" doing this to my car and my dad's car when we asked for their help and it _really_ annoyed us.  There might not be anything wrong with it, but when you're in the "try and take it easy on the car" mindset, this is infuriating.